# how to pass yubikey pin to openssl command in shell script

Tags: shell, openssl, certificate

I am trying to sign the CSR using opensssl command.
The certificate and root of trust goes to yubikey and yubikey act as HSM authority.
Every time i execute the command it asks for the Yubikey Pin.
How can i pass the PIN in command line so that i don't have to enter it manually and it can be shelled out completely.

openssl x509 -engine pkcs11 -req -days 30 -CAform PEM -CA "$subCert" -CAkeyform engine -CAkey "pkcs11:pin-value=$pin" -sha256 -CAcreateserial -in "$csr_file"     -outform DER -out "$crt_file"

this command should not be asking for PIN and should be taking pin from  "pkcs11:pin-value=$pin"

Answer (score 6):

Some background: it is proposed in various comments that different pin methods may resolve this issue, the options for passing a pin in are:

- specifying `-passin pass:123456` as in the yubikey docs [here](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/Certificate_authority.html).
- adding `PIN=123456` to your openssl configuration file in the `[pkcs11_section]`
- using a PKCS#11 URI as you have (which is passed through openssl to the pkcs11 library), something like: `-CAKey 'pkcs11:id=%02;type=private;pin-value=$PIN'`

*However*, all of of these seem to only impact the token pin, not the key pin (both of which are normally requested). It is unclear to me whether this is a [bug or a feature](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1728016).

Opensc has some [discussion](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/issues/1269) suggesting that you set `pin_cache_ignore_user_consent = true;` in the `framework pkcs15` section of your opensc configuration, however, this did not change the behaviour when I tested it.

**There (also? unclear if this is the same issue or not) appears to be an issue with yubikeys using slot 9c (index 02) where openssl always asserts `CKA_ALWAYS_AUTHENTICATE`, thus requiring pin entry for the key. This can be avoided by using slot 9a (index 01, `slot0-id1` or `pkcs11:id=%01;`) as suggested [here](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/issues/1545#issuecomment-522354169).**

You may also be able to use [OpenSC's pkcs11-tool](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Using-pkcs11-tool-and-OpenSSL) for some functions, which does not appear to have the same problem

Good luck!